# How to perform redirection without a file extension in the URL on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a GENERIC way to point a page to another page if the page has no extension specified without physically redirecting the user to the actual URL?

```
e.g. 
http://www.mydomain.com/  points to http://www.mydomain.com/public
http://www.mydomain.com/auth  points to http://www.mydomain.com/public/auth 
http://www.mydomain.com/auth/process points to http://www.mydomain.com/public/auth/process 
http://www.mydomain.com/auth/process/done points to http://www.mydomain.com/public/auth/process/done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

**Edit:**

Add this RewriteCond to check for an extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
```

Comment: sorry, didn't read, that you only want to 'redirect' if there's no extension, at first.

Comment: hi, thank for the reply. i'll try it out and get back to you in a few. btw, would you be so kind to post the exact order of the rules? sorry, really new to htaccess.

Comment: you're welcome! use this order:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
to try your rules you may use [R] instead of [L] so you see what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can do it by rewrite rules but you should know something about URL or some conditions about that to prevent rewritting other URLs.

for example rewrite rule for your given URL is:

```
RewriteRule ^auth/(.*)$  public/auth/$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^$   public [L]
```

Comment: that only works for the auth page. i'm looking for something more generic

Comment: @Jhourlad Estrella I edited the answer according to your edit. but if you want more, you should specify them.